# ¿Como puedo restaurar una base de datos en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de sql y estoy siguiendo un curso de internet el cual me pide restaurar una base de datos con una archivo .tar, estoy usando pgadmin4 postgresql16 al momento de hacerlo me lanza un error [image: ese es el error]
[image: esos son los detalles].
Quisiera que me ayuden uu

Comment: ¿Como tomaron ese backup? de que version es?

Comment: si no te da ningún mensaje de error, cómo podríamos adivinar nosotros?